# Delete content in a text file between two specific characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a simple bug tracker and am using a text file as the database. Right now I'm reading in all the information through keys and importing them into specific arrays.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    getline(bugDB, title[i], '@');
    getline(bugDB, importance[i], '!');
    getline(bugDB, type[i], '$');
    getline(bugDB, description[i], '*');
}
```

Here is what's in my (terribly unreadable) file

> Cant jump@Moderate!Bug$Every time I enter the cave of doom, I'm unable
>   to jump.*Horse too expensive@Moderate!Improvement$The horses cost way
>   too much gold, please lower the costs.*Crash on startup@Severe!Bug$I'm
>   crashing on startup on my Win8.1 machine, seems to be a 8.1
>   bug.*Floating tree at Imperial March@Minimal!Bug$There is a tree
>   floating about half a foot over the ground near the crafting
>   area.*Allow us to instance our group@Moderate!Improvement$We would
>   like a feature that gives us the ability to play with our groups alone
>   inside dungeons.*

Output: [image: output]

This works great for me, but I'd like to be able to delete specific bugs. I'd be able to do this by letting the user choose a bug by number, find the corresponding * key, and delete all information until the program reaches the next * key.

I'd appreciate any suggestions, I don't know where to start here.

Comment: Just write the content in some other file which you want to keep and then delete the existing file containing bugs and rename the new file to original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct mechanism for deleting some chunk of data from the middle of the file, no `delete(file, start, end)` function. To perform such a deletion you have to move the data which appears after the region; To delete ten bytes from the middle of a file you'd have to move all of the subsequent bytes back ten, looping over the data, then truncate to make the file ten bytes smaller.

In your case however, you've already written code to parse the file into memory, populating your arrays. Why not just implement a function to write the contents of the arrays back to a file? Truncate the file (open in mode "w" rather than "w+"), loop over the arrays writing their contents back to the file in your preferred format, but skip the entry that you want to delete.

Comment: Argh, I hadn't thought of that. I'll definitely give this solution a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

its only possible by manually copying the data from input file to output file and leaving out the entry you want to delete.

**but:** i strongly encourage the usage of some small database for keeping the informations (look at sqlite)

Also its a bad bugtracker if solving the bug means "delete it from database" (its not even is a *tracker*). give it a status field (open, refused, duplicate, fixed, working, ...).

Additional remarks:

1. use one array that keeps some structure with n informations and not n arrays.
2. please remind that someone may use your delimiter characters in the descriptions (use some uncommon character and replace its usage in saved text)

explanation for 1.:
instead of using

```
std::vector<std::string> title;
std::vector<int> importance;
std::vector<std::string> description;
```

define a structure or class and create a vector of this structure.

```
struct Bug{
  std::string title;
  int importance; // better define an enum for importance
  std::string description;
};
std::vector<Bug> bugs;
```

Comment: All great suggestions, thanks. For this project I'm stuck with using text files, but I'll be looking into sqlite regardless. I'll be separating completed bugs from current, which will need a status indicator anyway as you've mentioned. To your additional remarks - I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean by one array. And can I use any sort of character as a delimiter? Thanks again!

Comment: @user3419168 see my edit. i do not understand your second question about the delimiter. you chose the * @ $ and ! as delimiter that are quite common characters. i would choose something less common (actually i would use a database back end as mentioned earlier).

Comment: Just wondering if characters such as ¶, Ø, Ж, etc could be used as delimiters. In any case I'll be trying a few later today. Your structure suggestion makes a lot of sense, I'll be incorporating that into my project, it's much cleaner. thanks for all the help vlad!